# Browsing individual delivery server in Azure scaling environment

Tags: azure, deployment, scaling

We are on Sitecore 8.1 rev. 151207 (Update-1)

When we scale an existing Azure Delivery Farm, using Sitecore Azure module, we are seeing the additional server, but we are not seeing anything deployed to it.

I would like to know, how can we browse to these individual servers to confirm that they are there and deployed as expected?

Comment: Have a look at the technique described at https://stackoverflow.com/a/34833769/570705 which can be used to single out an Azure instance in an App Service cluster. Note that in order for this to work you’ll need to have ARRAffinity on in the App Service properties. (Best practice is to turn it off)